# Outgoing email not encrypted

Tags: email, postfix

I have a domain example.com being served from server.com. I am sending an email to gmail.com. The email I send uses TLS from example.com to server.com, but the mail is not encrypted from server.com to gmail.com.

server.com is a VPS that I set up mail and web servers on.

example.com is one of the virtual domains on the VPS.

Here is an example of the email headers:

```
    Delivered-To: receiver@gmail.com
    Received: by 10.236.191.7 with SMTP id c7csp2141557pjs;
            Tue, 1 May 2018 14:03:37 -0700 (PDT)
    X-Google-Smtp-Source: AB8JxZpwQHXweJ70K6vNAako5gqTtvni9ZUm6LC0Hfl0xAefu7wtGjSsnQHRHMKL/sLpOnicPwFM
    X-Received: by 2002:a63:3584:: with SMTP id c126-v6mr14324018pga.37.1525208616991;
            Tue, 01 May 2018 14:03:36 -0700 (PDT)

...
...

    ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
           spf=pass (google.com: domain of sender@example.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=sender@example.com
    Return-Path: <sender@example.com>
    Received: from server.com (server.com. [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
            by mx.google.com with ESMTP id d65si10640010pfd.182.2018.05.01.14.03.36
            for <receiver@gmail.com>;
            Tue, 01 May 2018 14:03:36 -0700 (PDT)
    Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of sender@example.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
           spf=pass (google.com: domain of sender@example.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=sender@example.com
    Received: from www.example.com (localhost [127.0.0.1]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)) (No client certificate requested) by server.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 7D74260383 for <receiver@gmail.com>; Tue,
      1 May 2018 14:03:36 -0700 (PDT)
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII; format=flowed
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Date: Tue, 01 May 2018 17:03:36 -0400
    From: sender@example.com
    To: receiver@gmail.com
    Subject: Hello
    Message-ID: <93768232f2ddc3a08237397@example.com>
    X-Sender: sender@example.com
    User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.2.3

    Test email body.
```

Any idea why the encryption is dropped?

EDIT:

My postconf -n output is:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
config_directory = /etc/postfix
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, server.com, , localhost
myhostname = server.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/chain.pem
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/privkey.pem
smtp_tls_loglevel = 2
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/chain.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 2
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-valias.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-vdomains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-vusers.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

And, this is my postconf -M output:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
dovecot    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

And, this is my mail.log:

```
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: setting up TLS connection from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: localhost[127.0.0.1]: TLS cipher list "aNULL:-aNULL:HIGH:@STRENGTH:!MD5:!DES:!ADH:!RC4:!PSD:!SRP:!3DES:!eNULL:!aNULL"
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read client hello
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write server hello
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write certificate
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write key exchange
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write server done
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write server done
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read client key exchange
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read change cipher spec
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read finished
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: localhost[127.0.0.1]: Issuing session ticket, key expiration: 1525220445
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write finished
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: Anonymous TLS connection established from localhost[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: BAB6360383: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=sender@example.com
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/cleanup[29153]: BAB6360383: message-id=<484bdbb907f3858ba851028998@example.com>
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/qmgr[29077]: BAB6360383: from=<sender@example.com>, size=745, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/smtp[29154]: initializing the client-side TLS engine
May  1 16:50:46 hwsrv-230549 postfix/submission/smtpd[29147]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
May  1 16:50:47 hwsrv-230549 postfix/smtp[29154]: BAB6360383: to=<receiver@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.197.26]:25, delay=0.65, delays=0.06/0.03/0.04/0.53, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1525218647 p84si10342745pfa.180 - gsmtp)
May  1 16:50:47 hwsrv-230549 postfix/qmgr[29077]: BAB6360383: removed
```

Any ideas?

EDIT 2:
I tried increasing the logging level to 4 and it did not provide any additional, useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postfix configuration above works. The problem was the VPS host. I contacted technical support to see if port 587 was being blocked by their firewall. They responded with:

> Kindly be infomed that since all the emails which are sending from our shared/VPS servers are decrypted due to outbound SMTP filtering, those emails are leaving our network in decrypted form.
>
> Actually, we utilize MailChannels as our outbound SMTP filter. This prevents messages that would be regarded as SPAM from leaving our network.

To resolve the issue, I had to pay $0.50 per month to be put on the MailChannels whitelist, and had to sign an anti-spam agreement.